# Filtering out items per year

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to filter a list of purchases from XML through the year they were made in. Problem being the date is formatted as such :Year/Month/Day. I got around this problem using the datetime library but now I can't use the year to filter out the purchases themselves.

```
def purchasesPerYear(year):
listPurchases = treeDoc.xpath("//purchase")
for purchases in listPurchases:
    nrPurchases = purchases.xpath("count(//purchase)")
    date = purchases.xpath("//purchase/@date_of_purchase")[int(nrPurchases)-1]
    dateParsed = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d")
    if year == dataParsed.year:
        for n in range(int(nrPurchases)):
            purchaseid = purchases.xpath("@puid")
        return purchaseid
    else:
        purchaseid = purchadses.xpath("//purchase/@puid")
        return purchaseid
```

print("purchase: ", compraPorAno(2017))

```
print("data: ", dataParsed)
```

Out of this code I either get the first purchase if the year is present in any of the purchases or all the purchases if the year isnt present. However, my first purchases year is 2016 and all the others were made in 2017. Basically if I input 2016 OR 2017 all I get is the first purchase instead of every purchase made in the year inputted.

```
<compra coid="CO01" id="U01" data_de_compra="2016/10/15" estado="entregue">
            <produto iid="I01" quantidade="1">
                <transportadora nome="CTT"/>
            </produto>
        </compra>
        <compra coid="CO02" id="U01" data_de_compra="2017/10/15" estado="emExpedicao">
            <produto iid="I03" quantidade="1">
                <transportadora nome="SEUR"/>
            </produto>
        </compra>
        <compra coid="CO03" id="U03" data_de_compra="2017/10/20" estado="entregue">
            <produto iid="I01" quantidade="1" avaliacao="4">
                <transportadora nome="MRW"/>
            </produto>
        </compra>
        <compra coid="CO04" id="U03" data_de_compra="2017/10/20" estado="entregue">
            <produto iid="I02" quantidade="1" avaliacao="5">
                <transportadora nome="UPS"/>
            </produto>
        </compra>
```

Comment: Have you consider to read you `XML` file(s) with `pandas` and then work with it?

Comment: Is the code right? You save the date into `dateParsed` but you're checking `dataParsed`

Comment: I'm doing a college assignment I need to do it with Python sadly :(

Comment: It's the only way i've found of getting the year out of the XML.

Comment: Can you provide the XML for us to test?

Comment: The only reason I haven't added the XML is because it is in portuguese and it is somewhat long. I would have to provide the portuguese code for it too if you want however.

Comment: Yeah, that's okay

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload files onto this site?

Comment: No. Just paste a section of the code like this: \```<XML>\```

Comment: Done. Compra = Purchase ,"data_de_compra" = date_of_purchase and the coid is the same as the puid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it by completely altering the way the code is formed:

```
listaCompras = treeDoc.xpath("//compra")
for elem in listaCompras:
    for n in range(4):
        data = elem.xpath("//compra/@data_de_compra")
        coid = elem.xpath("//compra/@coid")
compra = [0, 0, 0, 0]        
for g in range(4):
    dataParsed = [g]
    dataParsed = datetime.strptime(data[g], "%Y/%m/%d")
    compra[g] = (dataParsed.year, coid[g])
print(compra)

def compraPorAno(ano):
    for (a, b) in compra:
        if ano == a:
            print("ID: ", b)

print(compraPorAno(2017))
```

This code gives out the purchases ID if given the year the purchase was done in.